# Ejecutar programa .exe desde laravel

Tags: c#, laravel

Tengo un problema, estamos migrando un sistema de **PHP** puro a **laravel**, y hay una parte del sistema en la que ejecutamos un programa que habíamos hecho con C#, en php, simplemente ocupábamos el exec y poníamos el programa, así:

```
exec("C:\AppServ\www\creaRug\generxml\CreaRug.exe $exit");
```

Quisiera saber como seria en laravel porque cuando pongo igual el exec en laravel no aparece nada.

Answer (score 0):

Usa estos componente 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

$process = new Process('sh /folder_name/file_name.sh');
$process->run();

// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();
```

Comment: Y por ejemplo, mi variable en que parte se pondría? Muchas gracias por el apoyo!

Comment: Disculpame por no asistirte adecudamente ando desde el celular, donde dice file_name cambialo por una variable descompon un poco mas el string